# Running cucumber test changing variables?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

please allow me to show you this small piece of code from the testing I'm doing in a school platform:

```
  Background:
    I Enter the school page
    In Schools I navigate to:
      | Hierarchical level | Action      | Value          |
      | District           | expand      | District-A     |
      | School             | right click | Saint John's   |
    And Choose "Go to" on the Popup Menu
    And Zoom In To See More Options in Control Bar
```

So you see, I use this background to navigate in a small tree the website has.
My question here is can I instead of having "District-A" and "Saint John's" have for example two variables there like "district" and "school" so I can, when I run the tests on the command line, to had something like an extra parameter that says: I want this round of tests to have my "district" as "District-B" and have the "school" variable be one of the schools.
 First of all, would this be even possible?
Second, if it is, can someone give me a quick idea on how I could do this?

Thank you so much in advance-

Answer (score 1):

In cucumber you write scenarios to describe what you are trying to do, and perhaps explain why its important. You should not write steps that explain HOW you do something. Any steps that talk about clicking, expanding etc end up causing problems like you are experiencing.

So the first thing is to describe WHAT this background is trying to achieve, and WHY its important. After think about HOW and push that down into your step definitions and helper methods. After doing this you might end up with something like

```
Scenario: View a school
  Given there is a school
  When I view the school
  Then I should see the school
```

Now this might seem to simple, but thats the whole point. You should be making your website simple to use. So one of the first things you need to do is to be able to see a school. After you have this you might want to deal with lots of schools and think about finding a particular school. You then might end up with something like

```
Feature: Search for a school
  We want to be able to find a particular school

Scenario: Find a school
  Given there are lots of schools with one searchable
  When I search for the school
  Then I should see search results with one school
```

You might take a similar with Districts

```
Feature: Districts
  Schools are organised by districts. We would like to view all the schools in a district

  Scenario: View district
    Given there is a district
    When I view the district 
    Then I should see the district

  Scenario: See schools in a district
    Given there is a district
    And the district has some schools
    When I view the district
    Then I should see some schools
```

And so on ...

Notice how none of these scenarios have anything at all about pages, clicking etc. Its all WHAT and WHY not HOW. Also note how much simpler everything is.